# Multiple levels of private and public inheritance - unusual access

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class uvw;
class abc{
   private:
      int privateMember;
   protected:
    int protMember;
   public:
    int publicMember;
};

class def : private abc{
    public:
       void dummy_fn();
};

class uvw: public def{

};

void def::dummy_fn()
{
   abc x;
   def y;
   uvw z;
   cout << z.protMember << endl; // This can be accessed and doesn't give a compile-error
}
```

From what I understand, after `def` inherits privately from `abc`, `protMember` and `publicMember` become private in `def`. So, now when `uvw` inherits from `def`, it shouldn't have any data members. But we can weirdly access `z.protMember` from `dummy_fn()` , where as `z` shouldn't have a variable `protMember` in the first place. Am I going wrong anywhere?

Comment: Good question. It may have something to do with the fact, that `dummy_fn` is a member function of `def`. But it's just a guess.

Comment: Care to explain who ever you are Mr. Downvoter?

Comment: @mark he wanders alone, never finding his home, on the bit swept fields of the internet.  He has no name, but a calling.  He is, the Downvoter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were trying to access it from a free function, it wouldn't work. It does work in this case because `dummy_fn()` is a member function of `def`, so it has access to all the private things inside `def`. Since `z` *is-a* `def`, it has access to the private `def` members inside  the `z` instance too.

Or at least that's my guess. It's a strange case.

Comment: So, you mean `z`'s instance does have a `protMember` variable as well? I thought since everything is private in def, so `z` will not have a 'protMember' vaiable at all.

Comment: @AnkeshAnand access and object members are different issues. A derived class contains all of the members of its bases. The fact that you cannot always access them doesn't mean they are not there.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the clarification! You just cleared a major doubt off my head.

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally stumbled on a consequence of C++ being statically (and not dynamically) typed; as a result, access checks are performed at *compilation time* (not *runtime*) and thus reason about the *visible type* of the variable, and not its *actual dynamic type* (which is a runtime property).

To disentangle a bit the example:

```
class Base { protected: int prot; };

class Derived: private Base { void func(); };

void Derived::func() { std::cout << prot << std::endl; }
```

`func` is a member of `Derived`, as a result it can access all data members of `Derived`, both direct and accessible through inheritance:

- `Derived` inherits from `Base` directly, so `Base` is accessible
- `prot` is `protected` in `Base`, so `prot` is accessible to any child who can access `Base`

and thus as a result, `prot` is accessible in `Derived` (and thus in `Derived::func`).

---

Let us show off the importance of the access path:

```
class Another: private Base {};

class YetAnother: public Another { void func(); };

void YetAnother::func() { std::cout << prot << std::endl; } // ERROR (access)
```

Here, even though `Base::prot` is accessible in `Another`, since `Another` hides the fact it inherits from `Base` to everyone else, `YetAnother` cannot access `Base` and thus, transitively, cannot access `Base::prot`.

---

Let us show off the effect of static typing:

```
class Basic { void func(); };

class More: public Basic { public: int a; };

void Basic::func() { std::cout << a << std::endl; } // ERROR (unknown)
```

Here, even though a `More` object will have a `a` member, when we compile `Basic` we can only rely on what `Basic` knows. And `Basic` knows no `a`.

*Contrast this with a dynamic language such as Python where this would run fine for objects of class `More` and fail (`AttributeError` exception) for anyone not having a `a`.*

Answer (score 2):

Private inheritance only restricts the access from outside the class. It does not restrict what the derived class sees from the base class. So in your case, where `def` inherits privately from `abc`, `def` will still have access to all protected members of `abc`. Just clients of `def` won't have access to anything from `abc`; not even the `publicMember`.

Also, don't confuse private inheritance with not inheriting members or something.

> So, now when uvw inherits from def, it shouldn't have any data members.

This statement is not true.
`uvw` just as well has any data members that `abc` and `def` have, they are just not accessible from the outside.

See e.g. here for details: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/